# Should inverted color in SVG only take account of itself or also other elements?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, svg, mix-blend-mode

I get different results in different browsers for

```css
line {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 10;
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgb(231, 229, 218);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg width="100" height="100">
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100"/>
      </svg>
</div>
```

Firefox renders a white, Chrome a dark line. Which is correct?

Comment: I see the same in FF and chrome

Comment: @TemaniAfif So you see a dark line in both case? What version of Firefox are you on? Is it a non-current one (<62)?

Comment: yes both dark and I using V61.0.2 of FF

Comment: Okay, I think it changed with FF 62 then. My hunch is that it is a bug. I'll report and see what they say.

Comment: or simply wait for minor updates, I suppose it will get fixed with other bugs

Comment: @TemaniAfif It's the same problem in FF Nightly (64)...